# Add pagination to this following template

Tags: pagination, pages

```
<div id="omc-main-left-column" class="omc-content">  

    <?php query_posts($query_string . '&pagename=&page_id='); ?>
    <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=3'); ?>

    <?php  if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <h2><a class="blog-header" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

Published on   by .  -->

```
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('portrait', array('class' => 'omc-staff-photo omc-quick-frame')); ?></a>

            <div class="omc-blog-excerpt">

                <?php the_excerpt('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?>

            </div>

            <a class="omc-search-result-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More &raquo;</a>

        </div>

        <br class="clear"/>

        <div class="blog-margin-omc"></div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>


<?php else : ?>

<h2>Not Found</h2>
<p>Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>


<?php endif; ?>

    <div id="pagination-blog-margin">   

    <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>

    </div>

</div><!-- /omc-main-left-column -->            

<br class="clear" />
```

---

code for pagination
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 2)
 $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;

```
 global $paged;
 if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

 if($pages == '')
 {
     global $wp_query;
     $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
     if(!$pages)
     {
         $pages = 1;
     }
 }   

 if(1 != $pages)
 {
     echo "<div class='pagination'>";
     if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
     if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a>";

     for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
     {
         if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
         {
             echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
         }
     }

     if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>&rsaquo;</a>";  
     if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";
     echo "</div>\n";
```

Comment: There is no *actual question* being asked here; just some pasted code. The question cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Close-vote as *not a real question*.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have 2 queries, the second is overriding the first:

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&pagename=&page_id='); ?>
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=3'); ?>
```

Replace them with a single query:

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&pagename=&page_id=&posts_per_page=3'); ?>
```

Then modify your query as such:

```
'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )
```

e.g.

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&pagename=&page_id=&posts_per_page=3&page='.( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )); ?>
```

Comment: hey can i apply d same pagination logic for post????

Comment: i have a pagination code as follows when i click any one post in above code it will take me to another page but want to add pagination for that also is that possible i have used next previous post but i want to apply the following code is that possible

Comment: i have posted the code for pagination